# Compatible MySQL version

Tags: mysql, php-8.1

Have a wamp server running php8.1. I get many Deprecation Notice. I've searched that the problem is about MySQL version. Wamp has MySQL 5.7.36. Does anyone knows which MySQL version is compatible with php 8.1?

Comment: Please show us these Deprecation notices

Comment: WAMPServer can use (install an ADDON) for mutiple versions of MySQL as well as Apache/PHP/mariaDB etc

Comment: See the [Backup Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) and pick as many versions of all these a you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These deprecation notices most likely come from php, not MySQL / MariaDB.

Many php applications need to have their code tweaked to be fully compatible with php 8. If it's your code you can do that. Or, if it's not your code you might get a version of WAMP that uses php 7.0, 7.2, or 7.4.

Without seeing the actual deprecation notices the rest is guesswork.

And, if you're starting a new app do consider using MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.3+. 5.7 goes end-of-life in October 2023, which is not very long from now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about version of MySQL server. Check your source code how to make a connection. If you use mysql function, replace it by mysqli versions or use PDO library.